# Replace very near word to a number with another word

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

Replace very near string to a number with another string

```
a b c d a b c d e 23:12:00 k b c l d b d c e 12:02:10
```

How to replace first d before time (number) with another character f.it should be as below

```
a b c d a b c f e 23:12:00 k b c l d b f c e 12:02:10
```

OR ,

How to Replace cell with header .

```
[srinivas@examplewww ~]$ grep -oP '(cell">)[0-2][0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+'  test.html1
cell">06:25:50
cell">23:59:38
cell">23:17:50
cell">06:27:37
cell">06:07:38
```

it should be as below

```
   header ">06:25:50
   header ">23:59:38
   header ">23:17:50
   header ">06:27:37
   header ">06:07:38
```

Comment: Also, what's the rule?  `sed 's/d/f/2'` does what you request, but is probably not going to be suitable in the general case.

Comment: The two problem statements separated by **OR** are completely different.

Comment: both are .different. if first one is not possible then will use second one

Comment: 2 problem statements = 2 separate questions on SO.

Comment: For second case, do you want that indentation in line2 onward?

Comment: no indentation .Both are separate  questions

Comment: First problem: `perl -nE '$_ = reverse; s/(?<=[0-9])(.*?)d/\1f/g; $_=reverse; print' input.txt` I am assuming that `d` and `f` are placeholders and need not be single character strings in actual use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following solution will search for any number and if found it will start polling backwards to search `d` in the string and if found replace it with `b`.

Sample input:

```
echo $x
a b c d a b c d e 23:12:00 k b c l d b d c e 12:02:10
```

Solution using awk:

```
echo $x |awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~/[0-9]|-[0-9]/) for(j=i;j>=0;j--) if($j ~/d/) {gsub(/d/,"b",$j);break }}1'
a b c d a b c b e 23:12:00 k b c l d b b c e 12:02:10
```

Comment: Thanks .Working perfectly in all cases. if i want change below  20:00:00 .result should be 
a b c d a b c d e 23:12:00 k b c l d b b c e 12:02:10

Comment: Even when it is in -ve ,like -39:00:00 ,It should be change

Comment: @SrinivasNallapati , try now with negative numbers. did some minor changes in command.

Comment: Great .it is working fine ..i am using llike
`if($i ~/>[0-1][0-9]:..:..|>-[0-9][0-9]:..:../)`

Comment: Glad, your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/d([^d:]*([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])/f\1/g' file
```

and

```
sed -r 's/cell(">([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])/   header \1/' file
```

Both regexp pattern match and then use backreferences in the replacement side of the substitution.

Comment: Thanks Potong.It is working fine . if i want to change lines  which have lessthan   24:00:00 ,Then how can i give limit

Comment: @SrinivasNallapati see edit

Comment: Thanks for reply. By this we can not change 19:00:00 .by your command we can change  01,02,03 but not 04. Please suggest

Comment: @SrinivasNallapati see edit